# How to add autocomplete to custom taxonomy for CPT

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tax-query, autocomplete

I was following this tutorial,

http://gabrieleromanato.name/adding-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-the-wordpress-search-form/

and have it working like that fine. However, I am attempting to make this work to autocomplete based on the list from custom taxonomies I have created for a CPT. My search function looks like this,

```
function hbgr_search() {
        $term = strtolower( $_GET['term'] );
        $suggestions = array();

        $input_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'dealer-locator',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'zip_code',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $term ),
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'city_served',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $term ),
                ),
            ),
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $input_args );

        while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            $loop->the_post();
            $suggestion = array();
            $suggestion['label'] = get_the_title();
            $suggestion['link'] = get_permalink();

            $suggestions[] = $suggestion;
        }

        wp_reset_query();

            $response = wp_json_encode( $suggestions );
            echo $response;
            exit();

}
```

JS Code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        var url = MyAutocomplete.url + "?action=hbgr_search";
        $( "#search-dealer" ).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            delay: 300,
            minLength: 3
        });
    });

})( jQuery );
```

If I comment out my PHP line of $loop = .... and replace with this

```
$loop = new WP_Query( 's=' . $term );
```

Then the ajax autocomplete works fine (if I search for a post or page) so I know it is getting loaded right, just something funky with my tax queries?

I took the WP_Query section and tested it in its own file to be sure it worked, and it does.

EDIT:
If I change my function to this, it works as well, by returning a list with whatever I type in the search box...

```
$suggestions = array();
$suggestion['label'] = $_GET['term'];
$suggestion['link'] = 'http://google.com';
$suggestions[] = $suggestion;

$response = wp_json_encode( $suggestions );
echo $response;
exit();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please also add your ajax code to question. You should split it up. First use only PHP to make sure your query works. Then use ajax without PHP, just return a simple string or integer to make sure ajax works and only then put them together. If it still returns nothing, you've probably got a format / encoding problem. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Is `$_GET['term']` filled? I can not see how you send the `term` query var in the ajax request.

Comment: Yes it is getting filled

Comment: Sorry, I've checked and it is auto-sent by jquery-autocomplete script.

Answer (score 3):

The logic in the tax query is very unlikely to verify `true`.

Look at it:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
                  array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'zip_code',
                     'field'    => 'slug',
                     'terms'    => array( $term ),
                  ),
                  array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'city_served',
                     'field'    => 'slug',
                     'terms'    => array( $term ),
                  ),
),
```

If you read the tax query, it says: get posts that have assigned the same value (`$term`) in `zip_code` and `city_served` taxonomies.

Note that you have set the `AND` relation between both taxonomies and use the same `$term` variable for both. It is very unlikely a zip code and a city name has the same value.

Maybe you want this other logic:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
                  array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'zip_code',
                     'field'    => 'slug',
                     'terms'    => array( $term ),
                  ),
                  array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'city_served',
                     'field'    => 'slug',
                     'terms'    => array( $term ),
                  ),
),
```

Apart of that I don't see anything wrong in your code, although you are not showing the full code, so I can not been sure.

I've built a simple test using default post type, category and tag taxonomies ant it works:

PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_hbgr_search', 'hbgr_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_hbgr_search', 'hbgr_search' );
function hbgr_search() {
        $term = strtolower( $_GET['term'] );
        $suggestions = array();

        $input_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $term )
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $term )
                ),
            ),
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $input_args);

        while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            $loop->the_post();
            $suggestion = array();
            $suggestion['label'] = get_the_title();
            $suggestion['link'] = get_permalink();

            $suggestions[] = $suggestion;
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        $response = wp_send_json( $suggestions );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
function add_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui-styles','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-styles' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-autocomplete', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'my-autocomplete.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' ), '1.0', false );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-autocomplete', 'MyAutocomplete', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-autocomplete' );
}
```

JavaScript (my-autocomplete.js):

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        var url = MyAutocomplete.url + "?action=hbgr_search";
        $( "#search-dealer" ).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            delay: 300,
            minLength: 3
        });
    });

})( jQuery );
```

Search form:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" role="search">
    <input id="search-dealer" type="search" placeholder="Search" name="s">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great catch yeah I saw that last night as well and tried it, but still no luck!

Comment: Apart of that I don't see anythin wrong in your code. I've edited the answer; sample working code added.